# Rsyslog not logging events

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, syslog, rsyslog

I'm trying to stand up a syslog server to receive events from a piece of network equipment, but I can't seem to get it to actually log the events to disk. I can confirm that the connection is being made successfully, and that rsyslogd is getting the event, I just can't figure out why it's not *doing* anything with it. The only thing that gets logged is the startup of rsyslogd itself.

Config and debug outputs below, this was originally generated from the rsyslog chef cookbook, but I added a couple tweaks to fix the *super* deprecated syntax that it was complaining about.

`rsyslog.conf`:

```
$MaxMessageSize 2k
$PreserveFQDN off
$ModLoad imuxsock
$ModLoad imklog
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup root
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

`rsyslog.d/*`:

```
$DirGroup root
$DirCreateMode 0755
$FileGroup root
$template PerHostAuth,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/auth.log"
$template PerHostCron,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/cron.log"
$template PerHostSyslog,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/syslog"
$template PerHostDaemon,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/daemon.log"
$template PerHostKern,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/kern.log"
$template PerHostLpr,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/lpr.log"
$template PerHostUser,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/user.log"
$template PerHostMail,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/mail.log"
$template PerHostMailInfo,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/mail.info"
$template PerHostMailWarn,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/mail.warn"
$template PerHostMailErr,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/mail.err"
$template PerHostNewsCrit,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/news.crit"
$template PerHostNewsErr,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/news.err"
$template PerHostNewsNotice,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/news.notice"
$template PerHostDebug,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/debug"
$template PerHostMessages,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/messages"
auth,authpriv.*         ?PerHostAuth
*.*;auth,authpriv.none  -?PerHostSyslog
cron.*                  ?PerHostCron
daemon.*                -?PerHostDaemon
kern.*                  -?PerHostKern
lpr.*                   -?PerHostLpr
mail.*                  -?PerHostMail
user.*                  -?PerHostUser
mail.info               -?PerHostMailInfo
mail.warn               ?PerHostMailWarn
mail.err                ?PerHostMailErr
news.crit               ?PerHostNewsCrit
news.err                ?PerHostNewsErr
news.notice             -?PerHostNewsNotice
*.=debug;\
  auth,authpriv.none;\
  news.none;mail.none   -?PerHostDebug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
  auth,authpriv.none;\
  cron,daemon.none;\
  mail,news.none        -?PerHostMessages
:fromhost-ip,!isequal,"127.0.0.1" stop
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none    /var/log/messages
authpriv.*    /var/log/secure
mail.*    -/var/log/maillog
cron.*    /var/log/cron
*.emerg    :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit    /var/log/spooler
local7.*    /var/log/boot.log
$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog
```

Test event:

```
logger --server 127.0.0.1 --tcp --port 514 -p user.info test
```

`strace -f` of rsyslogd receiving the event, but doing nothing:

```
[pid 32310] accept(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(59755), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 11
[pid 32310] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP], ~[KILL STOP TTIN RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
[pid 32310] open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
[pid 32310] fstat(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=451, ...}) = 0
[pid 32310] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb290d18000
[pid 32310] read(12, "#\n# This file is managed by Chef"..., 4096) = 451
[pid 32310] close(12)                   = 0
[pid 32310] munmap(0x7fb290d18000, 4096) = 0
[pid 32310] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[KILL STOP TTIN RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 32310] fcntl(11, F_GETFL)          = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
[pid 32310] fcntl(11, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
[pid 32310] epoll_ctl(10, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 11, {EPOLLIN, {u32=2147497424, u64=140404628403664}}) = 0
[pid 32310] epoll_wait(10, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=2147497424, u64=140404628403664}}}, 128, -1) = 1
[pid 32310] recvfrom(11, "<14>Jul  7 22:41:54 stack: test\0", 131072, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 32
[pid 32310] gettimeofday({1467931314, 137777}, NULL) = 0
[pid 32310] epoll_wait(10, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=2147497424, u64=140404628403664}}}, 128, -1) = 1
[pid 32310] recvfrom(11, "", 131072, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 0
[pid 32310] epoll_ctl(10, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 11, {EPOLLIN, {u32=2147497424, u64=140404628403664}}) = 0
[pid 32310] close(11)                   = 0
[pid 32310] epoll_wait(10,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what the problem is? `logger`.

However `logger` tries to format the message it sends over the network is broken.

I cannot comprehend how such a simple utility can be broken.

I've wasted an entire day trying to debug a *perfectly valid config*.

Here's a test that isn't broken and won't waste your life:

```
echo "<165>1 2003-08-24T05:14:15.000003-07:00 192.0.2.1 myproc 8710 - - %% It's time to make the do-nuts." | nc 127.0.0.1 514
```

**edit:** Now that it's a day later and I'm no longer *visibly upset* I've gone back and compared the message sent by `logger` and the one above that I pulled from [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424). The message generated by logger is:

```
<14>Jul  8 16:39:08 user: test
```

Which is just *hilariously* wrong. The proper, equivalent message would be:

```
<14>1 2016-07-08T16:39:08.000000-07:00 syslog-01 myproc - - - user: test
```